# How to hide element when offscroll in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, display

I have the following code:

```
        document.addEventListener("scroll", inView);

        function inView() {
            if (document.getElementById("viewElement").getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight) {
            let top = document.querySelector("#top");
            top.style.display = "block";
            }
            else{
            top.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

What this function does, it displays an element that has the position of static when the user scrolls and the footer element is in view. I want to hide the element when the footer is out of view. What would be the best approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out IntersectionObserver API. It will allow you to react on footer going out of the viewport.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Thanks for this link. I found the information to solve my issue. I also watched a youtube video, Introduction to the Intersection Observer JavaScript API by Kevin Powell
that explained it further.